# PHP-Compressor || or && Jquery-Version ;)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm wondering if I can use the Jquery-Version of TinyMCE and the PHP-Compressor for TinyMCE simultaneously.

The problem: the normal version is initialized with the `TinyMCE.init`-Method, the Jquery-version width `$(ELEMENT).tinymce()` - and the PHP-Compressor only seems to support the first way of initialization.

Strangely I couldn't find any information about that on the web.

Anyone who can enlighten me?

Comment: Is there any difference in initializing the plugin with `TinyMCE.init` as opposed to `$(ELEMENT).tinymce()`?

Comment: it is, but not very much.

I will now use the PHP-Compressor and initialize TinyMCE with the "init"-method instead of using the Jquery.version.

Jquery-version and PHP-Compressor simultaneously seems impossible :(

thx for your comment :)

Comment: i highly suggest everyone not to use the Jquery-version, cause it is slow when it comes to typing and other things (the jquery object generation will take too much time i guess)